# How can I reject a mail sent to a specific user on postfix and dovecot?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

In my company, there are a couple of locked user accounts. Some spammer targets on one of them. The spammers send mails to the account every day.
How can I reject a mail that is sent to the locked user?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to reject mail *to* the locked user, not just mail from some known sender / domain? Then you should use `check_recipient_access` instead of `check_sender_access`.

For `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    . . . 
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/denied_recipients,
    . . .
```

And the `/etc/postfix/denied_recipients` has the same format, but per recipient:

```
lockeduser@example.com   REJECT   Mailbox unavailable.
```

As this is also a `hash:` Berkeley DB, remember `postmap /etc/postfix/denied_recipients`.

Answer (score 0):

In `postfix` you can create a file /etc/postfix/sender_access which basically looks like this:

```
# ADDRESS PATTERNS         # ACTION
sender@example.com         550 Blacklisted
domain.com                 REJECT
user@                      REJECT
```

Convert this to a hash using `postmap` and add a line to your configuration like this:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

However, this will reject or or blacklist a message with a response, and you may not want the sender to know that it is being rejected. You may also only want the mail to be rejected for a particular user, in which case I would suggest using `procmail` or a policy server. Procmail is powerful but can be hard to get into. Postfix's architecture means that an external server, even plain `spamassassin` may do what you require.